# React application crashing in chrome - Error code: Out of Memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to launch my very first React application, and when I try to launch it using "dev" script in package.json, then it crashes the chrome tab. In task manager ram consumption gets even to 7.5 GB

My code is:
src\index.jsx

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Header} from "./header";

window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('react_root'));
})
```

src\header.jsx

```
import * as React from "react";

export function Header(){
    return (
        <Header>
            <h1>Reddit for our own</h1>
        </Header>
    );
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="react_root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "skillbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:prod": "env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev": "env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const IS_DEV = NODE_ENV === "developement";

module.exports = {
    resolve:{
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json']
    },
    mode: NODE_ENV ? NODE_ENV : 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [{
            test: /\.[tj]sx$/,
            use: ['ts-loader']
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({ template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html') })
    ],
    devServer:{
        port: 8000,
        open: true,
        hot: false
    }
};
```

Console does not give any error, it is just the browser, which crashes because of memory.

Comment: _Please_ don't set up webpack and everything by yourself for your first React project - use e.g. https://vitejs.dev/

Comment: Well, I could try that aswell :) But maybe you see an error why it crashes? :)

Comment: Create new react app with `vite`

Comment: @raicha Not right off the bat, but I see bugs in e.g. `NODE_ENV === "developement"` -- it's `"development"`... the sort of things you shouldn't need to worry about with other tools.

Comment: And you don't need that `window.addEventListener` in your index.jsx.